# Regular expression that includes all keyboard characters except '~' and ','

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression that includes all keyboard characters except '~' and ','?

Comment: This is a trivial regex. Have you even tried?

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried this?

```
[^~,]
```

Now to exclude characters not in keyboard, I believe you have to include them all.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:"'`!@#$%^&*()\[\]{}_+=|\\-]
```

Which pretty much covers it (even though it looks like a crazy way to get things done). Maybe the problem definition can help you add more stuffs to exclude in the first list `[^~,]` than try to create a huge list of all keyboard chars.

Comment: However this will allow some special charcaters that are not in keyboad that might come acccidentally by doing copy nad paste from some text.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what language/tool you're using, but in Java I would go with this regex:

```
"[\\p{Print}&&[^~,]]"
```

That's the intersection of two sets: all printing ASCII characters, and all characters that aren't a tilde or a comma.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this for regex to work:

```
"[^~,][^~,]*"
```

because `[^~,]` negates `~` and `,`

`[^~,]*` means in zero or many copies of `~` and `,` (that is useless for our case)

and by putting `[^~,][^~,]*` gets you to negate one or more copy of `~` or `,`

Comment: There is a special quantifier for "one or more": `[^~,]+`

Answer (score 2):

A related one.

I wasted a lot of time searching, so below is the answer I came up with.

---

I wanted **all keyboard keys (including space and tab)**:

```
// all keys (including space and tab)
var allKeyboardKeysRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+={\[\}\]\|\\:;"'<,>\.\?\/  ]*$/;

// example tests
var nonShiftChars = "`1234567890-=  qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./ "
var shiftChars = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>? ";
var someAlphaNumeric = "aAbB12 89yYzZ";

// test with allKeyboardKeysRegex
allKeyboardKeysRegex.test(nonShiftChars);
allKeyboardKeysRegex.test(shiftChars);
allKeyboardKeysRegex.test(someAlphaNumeric);
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
```

---

if you want to **exclude some characters**, then just delete them from above 1st line regex line (allKeyboardKeysRegex).

Example:

```
// removing '~' and ','
var allKeyboardKeysRegexMinusSome = /^[a-zA-Z0-9`!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+={\[\}\]\|\\:;"'<>\.\?\/   ]*$/;
```

Hope that will help someone.

---

**Update**

List of all chars

```
"1234567890"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/    " (last 2 are space & tab here)
"~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/ \t\r\n   " (last 2 are space & tab here, all these chars are escaped with \)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
[A-Za-z0-9-]+[ 0-9A-Za-z#$%=@!{},`~&*()'<>?.:;_|^/+\t\r\n\[\]"-]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Reg-Ex for all supported key board chars worked for me :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!@?#"$%&:';()*\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>~` ]+$/
```

To except '~' and ',' chars :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!@?#"$%&:';()*\+\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>` ]+$/
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I see `;` exists twice in that series of chars. Though having it twice improves readability