# javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

how can i not allow these chars:

> \ / " ' [ ] { } | ~ ` ^ &

using javascript regular expression pattern?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705672/regular-expression-to-allow-a-set-of-characters-and-disallow-others

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152844/regex-for-alphanumeric-and-the-character, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763071/negate-characters-in-regular-expression, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834002/regular-expression-that-includes-all-keyboard-characters-except-and, ...

Comment: And (despite PHP tags): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778958/php-regular-expression-accept-selected-characters-only, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878715/checking-string-for-illegal-characters-using-regular-expression.

Comment: What do you need it for? It looks like some sort of security instalment, but anything you do in JavaScript can be overridden by a malicious user. Also, in general, it is a lot easier to avoid injection holes by specifying a list of allowed characters, that way you are also safe from anything you hadn't thought about.

Answer (score 1):

Check a string contains one of these characters:

```
if(str.match(/[\\\/"'\[\]{}|~`^&]/)){
  alert('not valid');
}
```

Validate a whole string, start to end:

```
if(str.match(/^[^\\\/"'\[\]{}|~`^&]*$/)){
  alert('it is ok.');
}
```

Comment: Or to remove those characters: `str = str.replace(/[\\\/"'\[\]{}|~\`^&]/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

**To specifically exclude just those characters (Just prefix with backslash)**

```js
const isNotSpecial = /[^\\\/\"\'\[\]\{\}\|\~\`\^\&]/.test(myvalue);
```

**To generally exclude all special characters**

```js
const isNotSpecial = /[^\W]/.test(myvalue);
```

Answer (score -2):

Another solution is encoding these special characters into the regular expression format.

Using package [`regexp-coder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexp-coder)

```js
const { RegExpCoder } = require('regexp-coder');

console.log(RegExpCoder.encodeRegExp('a^\\.()[]?+*|$z'));
// Output: 'a\^\\\.\(\)\[\]\?\+\*\|\$z'
```